# IndexError: list index out of range Python. Without using sort or sorted:

Tags: python, while-loop, range, outofrangeexception

I am having trouble with my code. I'm still new to Python, but I appreciate any push in the right direction. I am trying to sort a sequence of numbers and returns sorted. I'm not asking for the answer, but for guidance to help me correct my own code.

I'm not sure how to fix the out of range. Would I need to add -1 somewhere?

```
def interleaved(seq1,seq2):
    seq1= [-7, -2, -1]
    seq2= [-4, 0, 4, 8]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    res = []

    while i <len(seq1) and j <len(seq2):
        print(i,j,seq1[i],seq2[j])
        i+=1
        j+=1
        if seq1[i] <seq2[j]:
            print(res)
            i+=1
            res.append(seq1[i])
        if seq1[i]> seq2[j]:
            print(res)
            j+=1
            res.append(j)
    return res
```

Comment: You are incrementing i+=1 but seq2 has 4 elements so in the 4th loop the i will be out of range.

Comment: how would I append the last item to the list? slicing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here i'm taking *argv aguments so you can pass how many lists you want. Then am creating a main list with all lists joining together. Then i'm looping through elements and swapping if it's not in correct order

```
def interleaved(*seq):
    res=[]
    for x in seq:
        res.extend(x)
    
    for i in range(len(res)-1):
        if res[i] > res[i+1]:
            res[i],res[i+1]=res[i+1],res[i]
    
    return res

seq1= [-7, -2, -1]
seq2= [-4, 0, 4, 8]
print(interleaved(seq1,seq2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to better clarify the question and write what exactly you want to do. However, in this case, the out of range issue that you are talking about arises because you are increasing i and j before running the if loops.

```
while i <len(seq1) and j <len(seq2):
    print(i,j,seq1[i],seq2[j])
    i+=1
    j+=1
```

When this while loop starts at `i == 2` the third line of your code increases the value of `i` to 3, therefore the if loop cannot be executed because index is out of range.

You can solve this issue by adding a `break`, but when and where to add it would depend on what exactly you want your code to do.